# IntelliJ Idea 12.0 and WebLogic 12c

Tags: jakarta-ee, intellij-idea, weblogic

Does anybody know, is webloggic 12c supported in IntelliJ Idea 12.0?

When I am trying to add WebLogic server I get:

> "The selected directory is not a valid WebLogic home".

Comment: http://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5500851#5500851

Comment: Thanks a lot, very usefull information!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem was solved by adding `registry.xml` of WebLogic v.10.6 in `home directory` with Web Logic 12c. Thanks to Frederic Close.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are running Weblogic 12c, you can also add a registry.xml file for 12c instead of using the 10.x version.  See https://dzone.com/articles/using-intellij-idea-12 for an example file and explanation.  Simply tweak for your environment and place it in your WL home.